# How to make a TabBar button loading always the first view of a NavigationController

Tags: iphone, navigationcontroller, tabbarcontroller

How can I force a TabBar button to load always the first view of a NavigationController?

I don't want to load the last in time loaded view but always come back to the first view of that NavigationController scheme.

Thank You very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the top view when you tap a `TabBarItem` like so:

```
 [someNaviagtionController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Depending on how you set your `UITabBar` up, call it either from `tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:` or from `tabBar:didSelectItem`.

Comment: ok.. thank You! but I'm not able to listen to the selection.. How should I do? I've declared an IBOutlet UITabBarController, I've added UITabBarDelegate to the @interface and I've added this method to my implementation -(void)tabBarController: (UITabBarController *) myController didSelectItem: (UITabBarItem *) myBarItem

what is missing??
Thank You

Comment: perfect! I've made it!
And for popping to Root I've used popToRootViewControllerAnimated as GojaN suggested ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can call `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:`.
Take a look [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more info.